# How to assign the event which triggers Action Listener?

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, actionlistener

[Picture of some of the code that I'm trying to work with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4P7I.png)

I'm trying to make it in Java so that my labels can change what Icon they are displaying, and it seems like an ActionListener is the best way to do it, but I'm still a little confused.

Apparently ActionListener will trigger and perform the thehandler class (according to the tutorial I found) when an event occurs, though how do I declare what the event that triggers ActionListener will be? Also why I am I red lining?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: Don't post a picture of code. Instead post the actual code in the form of an [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You should try to implement MouseListener instead of the more generic ActionListener interface. This will make you listen to mouse clicks etc.

[Difference between Mouse Listener and Action Listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399652/difference-between-mouse-listener-and-action-listener)